# Adding a yes or no element in boxplot python

Tags: python, boxplot

This is what my data frame looks like:

```
     UnZThick  Yield  GWQual  HazRS  Contam
0           0      1       2      4       0
1           0      6       3      4       0
2           0      3       3      4       0
3           0      5       3      4       0
4           0      5       5      4       0
119         9      3       5      6       1
120         9      3       5      7       0
121         9      4       5      7       1
```

I want to create a boxplot with thickness vs yield with two separate boxplots for each level of thickness depending if it is contaminated or not (0=no, 1=yes).

So far I have:

```
#Boxplot of unsat thickness vs Yeild
df.boxplot(by= 'UnZThick', column = ['Yield'])
plt.xlabel('Unsaturated Thickness')
plt.ylabel('Yield')
plt.savefig('Plot3 as PNG.png', format='png', 
dpi=600],)
```

Comment: Please post the actual data, not a picture of it.

Comment: The ending square bracket `dpi=600]` seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1):

The seaborn library makes this very straight forward.  The boxplots will make more sense when applied to the entire df.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'UnZThick': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9],
 'Yield': [1, 6, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4],
 'GWQual': [2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5],
 'HazRS': [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 7, 7],
 'Contam': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]})

# If you want to make the Contam values yes/no
df['Contam'] = np.where(df['Contam']==1,'Yes','No')

# Use hue to split by Contam field
g = sns.boxplot(data=df, hue='Contam', y='Yield', x='UnZThick')
g.get_figure().savefig('img.png')
```

[image]

Comment: sorry.. i want all the values in dataframe from 0-121